# Is it possible to execute an after_filter in the event of a redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have some custom logging routines that record the pages hit along with some meta data about each page load. Among the information I'm logging, I'd also like to log the time it took to load a page, which obviously can't be done until AFTER the page has loaded. Using an after_filter is fine most of the time, but actions which update DB records and then redirect do not execute my after_filer code. Is there a way to still execute code in the event of a redirect?